# Yii2: Execute a redirect from static non-controller context

Tags: php, redirect, yii2

I have a function that calls our API called executeGetRequest (with variants for other HTTP methods). It is static and located in a base class. It is called from Controllers. If the API returns a 401 HTTP status code, executeGetRequest should redirect the user to the logout page on the "frontend" Yii2 project in order to clear the out of date session data.

My coworker and I have tried multiple different ways to redirect. $this->redirect() will not work because there is no $this object from a static context.

```
return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Url::to('login/user-logout'));
```

does not work.

```
Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Url::to('login/user-logout'))->send();
return;
```

does not work. We tried these with and without Url::to().

I was able to get a Yii::trace() in the conditional that checked for the 401 response. It works fine. So the problem is not the detection of 401 status codes, but the redirect.

Answer (score 5):

This **should** work

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(['login/user-logout'])->send(); return;
```

Possible causes why it's not working in your case:

1. This was ajax/pjax request.
2. You have used redundant Url::to() with wrong route.
3. You are expecting POST request which is often the case with `logout` actions.

`401` means it's probably #3. Try the same redirection mechanism but pointing to other route and/or remove `verb` behavior for `user-logout` POST action to verify it.